Div child height with items not 100% height when Browser is smaller
I'm not sure what I do wrong but when I make the height of the Browser smaller the child element is not 100% height. This happens only if there are items like a href or p. In the second Picture you can see the black Background of the body though I set "Menu-Container" to 100%.
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu-item1">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
  </div>
</div> 

.menu-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}

.menu-item1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background: dodgerblue;
}




overflow: auto to container

overflow: auto; will restrict the child container from filling it's containing space (if only declared on the parent div).

To force the parent div to fill the background regardless of height, try using min-height on both divs and viewport height on the child div.


body {
  margin: 0;
}
.menu-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /*
  align-items: stretch;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  */
}

.menu-item1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 15%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu-item1">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
  </div>
</div>



If you don't want to use vh units, you can try using flexbox on the html tag.


html {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.menu-item1 {
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  width: 15%;
}
<div class="menu-container">
  <div class="menu-item1">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you, this works fine without "position: absolute" but it should be work with "position: absolute". The problem is that I have two Div elements and want show each on top.

It should work with absolute positioning. I just commented it out in the example for demonstration purposes.

You did not define the height nor the width of the body.
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

This will make it so your body occupies the full viewport. Only then, you will define the height and width of the container.
.menu-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

This will make it so .menu-container occupies 100% of the height and width of its parent element, which is the body, which occupies 100% of the viewport, therefore, .menu-container will fill the whole viewport.
